# Android google maps marker disable navigation option

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

Im creating an app where users need to walk to a point on a map. But they need to find a route to the point by them selves.
Ive created a map with markers but by default if a user clicks on the marker a "start navigation" and "view in google maps" option is shown. Is it possible to disable these options ?

[image: The options that are shown on marker click]

The options that are shown on marker click

Answer (score 158, accepted):

This thing is called [Map Toolbar](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/interactivity#map_toolbar). You can disable it by calling  [UiSettings.setMapToolbarEnabled(false)](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/UiSettings.html#setMapToolbarEnabled(boolean)):

```
GoogleMap map;
....... //init map

map.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Thanks how did you find out the name of the toolbar ? i tried different search querys containing 'navigation marker' but couldnt find any link to maps toolbar

Comment: I keep monitoring Android Map releases - Map Toolbar was released last December :)

Answer (score 4):

You can also define `setMapToolbarEnabled()` from the XML using the following property:

```
map:uiMapToolbar="false"
```

Comment: this does not work by default, you should specify that in your xml `xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` - and I think `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` is more common (app and not map)

Answer (score 3):

In kotlin you can do:

```
map.apply {
   uiSettings.isMapToolbarEnabled = false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone needs to do this in Google Maps v2, you set it in the map options instead of setting it on the map directly. So like this:

`var mapOptions = new GoogleMapOptions().InvokeMapToolbarEnabled(false);`

Answer (score 0):

You can set toolbarEnabled MapView props to false