# How to hide "Navigation" and "GPS Pointer" buttons when I click the marker on the android google map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, marker

When I click the marker on the google map, "Navigation" and "GPS Pointer" buttons come out. How can I hide those two navigation buttons programmatically in android development?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android google maps marker disable navigation option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30354258/android-google-maps-marker-disable-navigation-option)

Answer (score 236, accepted):

For the button group you have outlined in red, you can disable it using the [setMapToolbarEnabled() method in UISettings](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/UiSettings.html#setMapToolbarEnabled(boolean)).

From the documentation:

> Sets the preference for whether the Map Toolbar should be enabled or
>   disabled. If enabled, users will see a bar with various
>   context-dependent actions, including 'open this map in the Google Maps
>   app' and 'find directions to the highlighted marker in the Google Maps
>   app'.

Code example to disable the two buttons with Java:

```
//Disable Map Toolbar:
mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
```

Just in case you were also wondering about the zoom buttons, you can disable them like this with Java:

```
mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
```

In Kotlin you can use property access syntax:

```
mMap.uiSettings.isMapToolbarEnabled = false
mMap.uiSettings.isZoomControlsEnabled = false
```

Comment: Hey, Can I get those button clicks?

Comment: By the way, mMap.uiSettings.isZoomControlsEnabled is false by default