# Hide get directions in SupporMapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps, supportmapfragment

I have a SupportMapFragment with a marker in it. By default when I tab on the marker two buttons appear in the right bottom corner: get directions and open map. Is there any way to disable this and prevent them from appearing?

Comment: checking the documentation always helps https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/interactivity

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hide "Navigation" and "GPS Pointer" buttons when I click the marker on the android google map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30430664/how-to-hide-navigation-and-gps-pointer-buttons-when-i-click-the-marker-on-th)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do as follows:

```
GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
```

Disable Map Toolbar:

```
mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
```