# What are the name of this buttons an how can i deactivate this?

Tags: button, 3d

If i zoom the map to maximum there arise the buttons in printscreen and the map turn a little to horizon (like 3d view). What is the name of this buttons and how can deactivate this (also deactivate this 3D view)
I don't mean the "Navigation Button" and "GPS Pointer Button".

[Printscreen where you can see the buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALCUp.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide "Navigation" and "GPS Pointer" buttons when I click the marker on the android google map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30430664/how-to-hide-navigation-and-gps-pointer-buttons-when-i-click-the-marker-on-th)

Comment: Hi thanks, but for this i need to know the names for this buttons?

Comment: They are called the "Navigation Button" and "GPS Pointer Button". They are located on the Map Toolbar.

Comment: No this are the names of your buttons, but not the name of the buttons in my screenshot. Pls check my screenshot.