# How to disable map toolbar

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

MapToolbar along with a marker is shown on map, when toolbar is clicked it redirects to google map. I want to disable this functionality.

[image]

**map_view.xml**

```
 <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/summary_mv_map"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        map:liteMode="true"/>
```

what I tried: added `mapView.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false)`, but not able to resolve getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled().

**Note: Don't want to remove marker**

Comment: Try this: `googleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);` Refer [this](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/UiSettings.html#setMapToolbarEnabled(boolean)) for more information.

Comment: tried but this code is for GoogleMap and not for MapView

Comment: `mapView.getMap()` returns the GoogleMap.

Comment: cannot resolve mapView.getMap()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide "Navigation" and "GPS Pointer" buttons when I click the marker on the android google map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30430664/how-to-hide-navigation-and-gps-pointer-buttons-when-i-click-the-marker-on-th)

Comment: @xomena before saying duplicate could you please read the entire question and read line "what I tried..."

Comment: Maybe you can post more Java code that demonstrates how this issue is different from another one. I can see that all replies repeat the same answer from the mentioned question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get `GoogleMap` object via `getMapAsync`, after that disable toolbar

```
mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below line to enable and disable Map toolbar

```
googleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
```

by-default it is true, make it false.

Answer (score 1):

```
map.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        return true;
    }
});
```