# How can I disable buttons to open google Maps - Google API android studio java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps

I am developing an app that uses Google Maps API and I was wondering how to disable/hide the google maps icons that appear on the right bottom corner when the user clicks on a marker?

[image]

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {


    map = googleMap;

    //enable the zoom in and out buttons bottom right
    map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        destinationPassed = extras.getString("key");
    }

    //enables the set view to current location top right
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    LatLng place = getLatLngFromAddress(destinationPassed);

    float zoom = 14.5f;
    if(place != null) {
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(place, zoom));
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(place)
                .title(destinationPassed));
        Toast.makeText(Map.this,"Click on the Marker to select the trip",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    } else{
        LatLng current = new LatLng(currentLat,currentLong);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(current, zoom));
        Toast.makeText(Map.this,"Location Could Not be Found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30430664/1238965

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/marker#introduction