# How to disable navigation buttons that appear when tapped a marker in Google maps with Flutter 1.0?

Tags: android, google-maps, mobile, dart, flutter

[Directions Buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBOGB.png)

I want to remove those buttons because I want to put the route implementation when I tap a button inside a Bottom sheet widget. My other question is, how Can I use the routes in Google maps inside my App and not redirected to Google maps? Do I need to enable the Routes API?

This is the same question in Android. 
[Android google maps marker disable navigation option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30354258/android-google-maps-marker-disable-navigation-option)

Answer (score 26):

[google_maps_flutter] Support enable/disable **MapToolbar**.

Add this line inside your **GoogleMap** widget to enable or disable MapToolbar.

```
GoogleMap(

mapToolbarEnabled: false,

)
```

PS : `consumeTapEvents: true,` 
stops recentering the map and marker's InfoWindow.

Answer (score 7):

When Creating a Marker set `consumeTapEvents` to **true**.

```
Marker(
    markerId: MarkerId('0'),
    icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
    position: LatLng(51.522522, -0.141198),
    consumeTapEvents: true
);
```

Tested on *google_maps_flutter: 0.5.16* with *Flutter v1.7.3*

From `consumeTapEvents` docs

> True if the marker icon consumes tap events. If not, the map will
>   perform default tap handling by centering the map on the marker and
>   displaying its info window.

Comment: This also makes it stops recentering the map on the selected marker and shows it InfoWindow. Do you know to make it at least keeps showing the marker info?

Comment: @FelipeCésar Not at the moment but it will be possible soon https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/851

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much for sharing it